# Stacked bar plot from Dataframe using groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe and I am trying to create a stacked bar plot

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def classify_data():
    race = ['race1','race1','race1','race1','race2','race2','race2', 'race2']
    qualifier = ['last','first','first','first','last','last','first','first']
    participant = ['rat','rat','cat','cat','rat','dog','dog','dog']
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'race':race,
         'qualifier':qualifier,
         'participant':participant

        }
    )
    pprint(df)
    df2 = df.groupby(['race','qualifier'])['race'].count().unstack('qualifier').fillna(0)
    df2[['first','last']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
    plt.show()



classify_data()
```

I could manage to obtain the following plot. But , I want to create two plots out of my dataframe

One plot containing the following data for the qualifier 'last'

```
Race1 rat 1
Race1 cat 0
Race1 dog 0 
Race2 rat 1
Race2 dog 1
Race2 cat 0
```

So the first bar plot would have 2 bars and each bar coded with a different color for the count of `participant`

Likewise a second plot for qualifier 'first'

EDIT:

```
  Race1 rat 1
  Race1 cat 2
  Race1 dog 0 
  Race2 rat 0
  Race2 dog 2
  Race2 cat 0
```

From the original dataframe , I have to create the above two dataframe for creating the stacked plots
[image: plot]

I am not sure how to use the groupby function and get the count of 'participant' for each 'qualifier' for a given 'race'

EDIT 2 : For qualifier 'last' the desired plot would look like( blue for rat , red for dog).

[image]

For qualifier 'first'

[image]

Could someone suggest me on how to proceed from here?

Comment: So for each column, you want a stacked plot?

Comment: @QuangHoang . No not for each column. For the qualifier , first and last, I  want two separate stacked plots. So the first bar plot would have 2 bars and each bar coded with a different color for the count of `participant`

Comment: it's really hard to follow what you want to achieve, is there a way you can manually create the plots for clarity sake?

Comment: @ Yuca please check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you want:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['race','qualifier','participant'])
         .size()
         .unstack(level=-1)
         .reset_index()
      )

fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12,6),sharey=True)
for ax,q in zip(axes.ravel(),['first','last']):
    tmp_df = df2[df2.qualifier.eq(q)]
    tmp_df.plot.bar(x='race', ax=ax, stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Natasha see edit for correct coloring of participants.

Comment: Excellent! thanks a ton. Can this be plotted in plotly using df2?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with plotly.

Comment: No issues, I'll try

Comment: @ Quang Hoang Can I select which qualifier to plot? for example just 'last' or just 'first' ? In my real example , I have 10 qualifiers first, second,..., ten

Comment: If you want them all, you can replace `['first','last']` by, for example: `df2.qualifier.unique()`. But then you need to match the number of qualifiers with that of `axes`.

Comment: @Quant Hoang Could you please explain the code a bit` .unstack(level=-1)
         .reset_index()` ? And can we set titles to subplots?

Comment: It's the same with `.unstack('participant')` (note that `participant` was last in the groupby list. I want `participant` to be columns so `df.plot.bar` will color them. Finally subplot title: `ax.set_title()`.

Comment: I am trying to set the font size `    plt.tick_params(labelsize=4)
` this changes the font size of only the last subplot . Is there a way to set the font size of a specific subplot alone?

Comment: Similar to `set_title()`, replace `plt` with `ax`.

Comment: Is there a way to define the order of the labels? I see the labels are sorted alphabetically. I'd rather prefer customizing it according to the user input. e.g rat cat and dog. Thanks a lot

Comment: You could define your column list in order `cols = ['rat', 'cat', 'dog']` and then instead of `df2[df2.qualifier.eq(q)]`, use `df2.loc[df2.qualifier.eq(q), cols]`